# How to get All Users in the organization with their member Groups using MS Graph in a single request

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to retrieve Users in an organization including Groups that each User is a member of, in a single call to Microsoft Graph?

Something like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=MemberOf`

This call does not return the Member groups. If I call the beta endpoint with same URL though I get the member groups in the response. the problem with the beta end point is that it returns a big response and I could not find a way to combine `$expand` with `$select` to only return the `MemberOf` property for each User and User's id field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This call does not return the Member groups. If I call the beta
>   endpoint with same URL though I get the member groups in the response.
>   the problem with the beta end point is that it returns a big response
>   and I could not find a way to combine $expand with $select to only
>   return the MemberOf property for each User and User's id field.

Not all relationships and resources support the `$expand` query parameter, `$expand` is only supported for beta and typically returns a maximum of 20 items for the expanded relationship. And not all resources or relationships support using `$select` on expanded items, I also tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$expand=memberOf($select=id,name)` in beta, the error prompts valid for this. For the details, please read [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#expand-parameter).

Comment: Thanks. Both answers are equally good and clear, I accepted this one that came earlier.

Answer (score 1):

According to the introduction of [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#expand-parameter), "with Azure AD resources that derive from directory Object, like user and group, $expand is only supported for beta and typically returns a maximum of 20 items for the expanded relationship".

Base on my test, you can use this API below to list out all the memberof.

```
'GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/memberOf
```

So there is no way to retrieve Users in an organization including Groups that each User is a memberof by using a single call to Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 0):

As other has mentioned, it's not possible with a single request.

For retrieving all users of our organization, and the groups they are members of, I resolved to this

- Fetch all groups (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/)
- For each group, fetch all members (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/[groupId]/members)
- In memory flatten the groups (a group can have another group as a member), so that groups only has users as members, and includes any member groups users.

This produced a list of groups, each with a list of all users that are directly or indirectly (user could be a member of a group that the original group has as a member). Should be relatively easy to convert it to a list of users each with a list of groups they are members of, if that is what you need.